# iOS - Image picker like the Facebook App?

Tags: ios, facebook, image, uiimagepickercontroller

Does anyone know of a control for iOS applications that looks similar to the image picker found in the Facebook app for iOS?  It allows for multiple image selection, transitioning over to the camera, only displaying selected images, etc.  I haven't located anything that is close to this control anywhere, but figured someone here might.

Comment: @Shadowman Any update on that?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score -5):

It is known as GrabKit, It is a free control under MIT lisence.

You may download it from [here](http://goo.gl/GZ75L2) and next time please make sure to do proper research on google before asking questions.

Comment: Not what I was looking for at all.  I'm looking for a UIImagePickerController replacement that *looks* like the one from the Facebook app.  I'm not looking for something to pull photos from Facebook.  Next time please make sure to read the question before answering.